# Angular2 @Injectable not working

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, injectable

I have an `@Injectable` class with a get-function in Service.ts create. This function should return one Array and also get any array. But it returns `null`. If I write this directly in a `@Component`, then it does get the array. What am I doing wrong?

*service.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class Arr_selected {
  private arr = [];
  get(arr_selected: any[]){
      for(let key in arr_selected) {
          if (arr_selected.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              this.arr.push([key]);
              return this.arr;
          }
      }
      console.log(this.arr);

  }

}
```

*component.ts*

```
import {Arr_selected} from './service.ts';
export class Component implements DoCheck, OnChanges, OnInit {
....
constructor( public arr_selected: Arr_selected)
.....

ngOnInit{

     let chk = this.ChkBoxValue;

     let arr = [];

/// **this not working Array is null**/////
     arr=(this.arr_selected.get(this.ChkBoxValue));

/// **this is working Array is not null**////
     for (let key in this.ChkBoxValue) {
            if (this.ChkBoxValue.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              arr.push(this.ChkBoxValue[key]);
         }
       }
        console.log(arr); 
}}
```

Comment: are you importing the service and injecting it into the component?

Comment: Thanks , yes , I' m importing with ->  import {Arr_selected} from'./servece.ts;

Comment: a plunker perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

i thinks below should work

```
@Injectable()
export class Arr_selected {
      get(arr_selected: any[]){
          arr = [];
          for(let key in arr_selected) {
              if (arr_selected.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                  arr.push([key]);
                  return this.arr;
              }
          }
          console.log(this.arr);

      }
```

I think the "this" operator is causing the problem for you . You have arr also defined in the component . this might be conflicting which arr to use.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working, without 'this' I get an error.

Comment: you have to move the arr[] to inside the function as shown in my code. If you you leave it as a class variable then you have to keep this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Above code you have written your file name as service.ts
```

and importing from ./servece.ts

```
   import {Arr_selected} from'./servece.ts;
```

May be its typing error here ,
also are you adding your service in provider of component ?.

Comment: Thanks, I written correct,  it was typing error ))   -->   " import {Arr_selected} from './service.ts'; "   I'm adding with providers: [ Arr_selected]